# AngularUI: range datepicker don't block dates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can anybody help? 
I wanted in my start-datepicker blocked dates after end-date and blocked dates in end-datepicker before start-date.
I used angularui datepickers.
I tried to do this using this code:

```
  $scope.start = new Date();
  $scope.end = new Date($scope.start.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  $scope.minStartDate = 0; //fixed date
  $scope.maxStartDate = $scope.end; //init value
  $scope.minEndDate = $scope.start; //init value
  $scope.maxEndDate = $scope.end; //fixed date same as $scope.maxStartDate init value

  $scope.$watch('start', function(v){
    $scope.minEndDate = v;
  });
  $scope.$watch('end', function(v){
    $scope.maxStartDate = v;
  });
```

And here's plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/tTBcSZE08VYCpitdhCRA?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your plunker with the necessary changes, basically you were setting `minDate` and `maxDate` incorrectly.You have declared date options but there is no such object in your controller, so I've added two date-options object for the calendars respectively. Here is the [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/Acsich1C8hQ15GqxiAjH?p=preview) code.

Changes in your JS are as below

```
    $scope.datePicker ={};
    $scope.start = new Date();
    $scope.end = new Date($scope.start.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    $scope.datePicker.minStartDate = 0; //fixed date
    $scope.datePicker.maxStartDate = $scope.end; //init value
    $scope.datePicker.minEndDate = $scope.start; //init value
    $scope.datePicker.maxEndDate = $scope.end; //fixed date same as $scope.maxStartDate init value

$scope.$watch('start', function(v) {
            $scope.datePicker.minEndDate = v;
            $scope.dateOptions2.minDate = v; //chabge the same in date options object to reflect in UI
        });
        $scope.$watch('end', function(v) {
            $scope.datePicker.maxStartDate = v;
            $scope.dateOptions1.maxDate = v;
        });
    //create two separate objects for date options where you can set ,in and max date..
        $scope.dateOptions1 = {
            //dateDisabled: disabled,
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            maxDate: $scope.datePicker.maxStartDate,
            minDate: $scope.datePicker.minStartDate,
            startingDay: 1
        };
         $scope.dateOptions2 = {
            //dateDisabled: disabled,
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            maxDate: $scope.datePicker.maxEndDate,
            minDate: $scope.datePicker.minEndDate,
            startingDay: 1
        };
```

Changes in your HTML as below

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                  ng-model="start" 
                  is-open="popup1.opened" 

                  datepicker-options="dateOptions1" 
                  close-text="Close" 
                  alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </p>

        <hr>

        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                  ng-model="end" 
                  is-open="popup2.opened" 

                  datepicker-options="dateOptions2" 
                  close-text="Close" 
                  alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </p>

  </div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped you ! Happy coding mate :)